# Excel cell being used as a string argument not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm playing around with converting Excel sheet names to index numbers and back again.

[image]

Column A is just the numbers one to ten.

Column B is a function I got off the internet to treat column A as an index number and convert it to a sheet name.  For completeness, the formula in row 1 shows "=INDEX(ListSheets,A1)", and ListSheets is
[image]
This is filled down and all working.

The problem is taking the sheet name and going back to an index.

Column C just says "=B1" and filled down.  I did this to make sure there wasn't any other mysterious problems.

Column D row 1 says "=SHEET(B1)" and filled down.
Column E row 1 says "=SHEET(C1)" and filled down.

The problem is they ALL SHOW the number 2, which is incorrect.  It should show the original value in column A.  When I originally ran these formulae in sheet1, the number 1 appeared all the way down, so the number 2 is probably the index number of the sheet that I'm currently working on.

As you can see in the first screen dump, cell F4 shows "=SHEET("PLTR_Profile")", and correctly gives an index number of 4.

Why can't I reference a cell to be used as a string argument?

For completeness, cell E4 is dumped below too.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the format of column C to string?

Comment: @Leonhard Euler Yes.  I just tried again and ran the formulae down.  No change.

Comment: Which index of worksheet are you working in? I.e., if it's `2`, then we could surmise that your `=SHEET()` function is getting a blank value.

Comment: As for the `Sheet()` function, I was able to get it working by referencing an actual sheet range object, not just the string literal of the sheet name. The documentation suggests you should be able to reference the sheet by name, but I also get `2` when I attempt that. So `=SHEET(INDIRECT(C1 & "!A1"))` should do the trick. (sorry for the delayed reply).

Comment: I suspect that odd behavior is because it's first seeing `C1` and not even bothering to get the text in that cell before telling you what sheet you can find `C1` in. Another option is to force it to eval `C1` by wrapping it in a function like `=SHEET(TRIM(C1))` or an even smaller workaround `=SHEET(+C1)`. Seems like a silly order-of-operations workaround.

Comment: @JNevill Yes using INDIRECT() worked for all of my sheets except row 5 (index 5), probably due to the space in the sheet name.  Using TRIM() worked for all of the sheet rows.  Very good!  But why is this sheet() function different?  Is there something I can read to understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting my comments into an answer since it's worth the write-up:

The [`SHEET()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sheet-function-44718b6f-8b87-47a1-a9d6-b701c06cff24) function takes in a parameter called `Value`

The `Value` parameter definition is:

> Optional. Value is the name of a sheet or a reference for which you
> want the sheet number. If value is omitted, SHEET returns the number
> of the sheet that contains the function.

Note that it says that this value can be one of two things:

1. *The name of a sheet* (which would be a string literal)
2. *The reference for which you want the sheet number* (or in other words a cell or sheet reference)

This is the difference between `"Sheet1"` (the name of the sheet, a string literal) and `Sheet1` (the reference to the sheet itself).

Because excel can take either-or, what it appears to do is first checks to see if it's a reference. If so it doesn't bother to evaluate that reference, but rather spits out the Sheet index for that reference. So `Sheet(Sheet2!A1)` is going to spit out the index for `Sheet2` EVEN if `Sheet2!A1` has a value like `Sheet3` in it. Excel doesn't bother evaluating because, by definition, if a reference to a sheet or range is supplied for `Value` then it spits out the sheet index for that reference.

To get around this, for your usecase where you have a string literal of a sheet name in a cell, you can use `INDIRECT()` to turn that string literal into a reference:

```
 =Sheet(INDIRECT(C1 & "!A1"))
```

Which (as you note in the comments) breaks if the sheet has a space, where different reference style is needed in `Indirect()` complicating the formula.

Or.. you can force excel to evaluate the content of the cell so that `Sheet()` gets the value/string-literal in the cell instead of the reference (as the reference would already be evaulated at this point):

```
 =Sheet(Trim(C1))
 or
 =Sheet(+C1)
```